# when exception occurs in a method of a class , will the class assembly have any details about it in c#

Tags: c#, exception

when exception occurs in a method of a class, will the class assembly have any details about it in c#.

For Example :-

I have a class A and one static method in class A.
I have another Class B and am calling that static method from here.
If any exception occurs in that method, will the class assembly of A or B have any details ??

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you your code looks like...

```
class B {

void SomeMethod(){

    A.StaticMethod();
}
```

?? if so then yes you can catch exceptions that are raised from A

```
class B {

void SomeMethod(){
    try {
        A.StaticMethod();
    }catch(/*Specific*/Exception ex){
      //ex.message
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry that's dumb question. but I wanted to know if we can see in class A that staticmethod has been called and exception thrown.. Thats a stupid thing though.. just wondering..